# Why does this common lisp macro not evaluate the first s-exp?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, ccl

I studied [define-easy-handler macro from the hunchentoot package](https://github.com/edicl/hunchentoot/blob/24f638f8d01fc5f15d1169be1de944392b38d1a2/easy-handlers.lisp) (which creates a function with the name NAME), and got the defun part to work, but I can't get this macro to push NAME to a list called `*observers*`:

```
(defmacro add-observer (name params &body body)
  ;; add NAME to the list *observers*
  `(push ,name *observers*)
  ;; define a lisp function with the name NAME
  ;; with key arguments given in PARAMS
  `(defun ,name (&key ,@(loop for p in params
                                collect p))
       ,@body)))
```

An example call to `#'add-observer` is:

```
(add-observer below-80 (id blood-sugar)
              (when (< blood-sugar 80)
                (format t "Patient No: ~A is hypoglycemic." id))
```

The function NAME is defined and works fine, but the NAME is not added to the list `*observers*`. It does not matter if I put both s-expressions inside a progn or not. The macroexpand clearly shows the absence of the call to `push` with and without a progn. What am I interpreting wrong?

## EDIT

When I try this with a progn like:

```
`(progn
  (push ...
  (defn ...
```

it fails with `Unbound variable: below-80`. And when I put the backquotes back to the #'push and #'defun, again #'push doesn't work.

Comment: Works very well for me with a `progn`, what are you observing when you add that?

Comment: @Madara Uchiha I added  what is wrong with my use of progn. Probably I  misuse progn.

Comment: If this is your real macro then `(loop for p in params collect p)` is simply `(copy-list params)`. However, the copy seems unnecessary here.

Comment: @coredump Thank you for the `copy-list`. I tend to spend more time writing code than learning existing functions. I added `copy-list` to my armamentarium.

Comment: @coredump Oh, and just `(&key ,@params)` is enough, too. I guess, that's what you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro gets the source form and computes the first result form: `(push foo *observers*)` and then this form is returned into the nirvana of the garbage collector, since it is not stored anywhere, not returned to any caller, not executed, ... It's garbage, immediately. So a clever compiler might even remove it...

The macro form then computes the second form `(defun ...)`. This form is returned from the macro and then later executed.

Either you want to execute the first form at macro expansion time, then you would need to make it executable - by removing the backquote and comma.

Or you want to include it into the generated source code, then you need to return a `progn` form, which encloses all the sub-forms.

You also might want to think about the effects of `PUSH` vs. `PUSHNEW`, when a macro form gets executed / expanded multiple times...

**Unwanted evaluation of symbols when using macros**

**Remember**: symbols are variables in Lisp code. If you want to treat them as symbols as themselves, then you need to quote the symbol or the data structure, where they occur.

Say, your form is:

```
(add-observer below-80 ...)
```

That means`below-80` is unquoted.

Now you generate code where the symbol is unquoted, too.:

```
(push below-80 ...)
```

Naturally, this tries to evaluate the *variable* `below-80`, which seems to be unbound in your code.

If you want `below-80` treated to be a *symbol* during evaluation, you have to quote it: `'below-80`. Your generated code should look like this:

```
(push 'below-80 ...)
```

Quote it either in your code

```
(add-observer 'below-80 ...)
```

or by the *macro* into the expansion:

```
(push 'below-80 ...)
```

The backquote template for that is

```
`(progn
   (push ',name ...)
   ...)
```

Comment: My intention is the second case. Would you mind to show the correct use of the progn here?

Comment: @barerd: you need to look at the expansion. If you don't want to evaluate something, you have to *quote* it somewhere. Either in the code or in the macro expansion.